# Django time difference with F object

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
  extra_days = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  due_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Where `due_date` is the date the assignment is due and `extra_days` is the number of extra days given after the due date to finish the assignment.

I want to create a query that returns all rows where `due_date + extra_days` is greater than the current date.  Here's what I am doing:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import F
from datetime import datetime

cur_date = timezone.make_aware(datetime.now(), timezone.get_default_timezone())
a = Assignment.objects.filter(extra_days__gt=cur_date - F('due_date'))
```

When I print `a`, I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 204, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 117, in _warning
_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2013-09-01 02:54:31'
```

If I do a time difference that results in, say, 3.1 days, I'm assuming the days difference would be still be 3.  I think it would more correct to do something like this:

```
a = Assignment.objects.filter(due_date__gt=cur_date - timedelta(days=F('extra_days')))
```

But that also results in an error.

How can I do this without writing a raw SQL query?

Comment: Convert both date into `timedelta` and subtract.

Comment: Do you mean something this: `a = Assignment.objects.filter(extra_days__gt=timedelta(cur_date - F('due_date')).days)`  I get this error: `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: ExpressionNode`

Comment: You can do using django ORM. refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42390145/4070498)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like what I'm trying to do is not possible.  I ended up writing a raw query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM app_assignment WHERE DATE_ADD(due_date, INTERVAL extra_days DAYS) > utc_timestamp()")
```

I was so repulsed at not being able to use the ORM for doing something so seemingly simple that I considered trying out SQLAlchemy, but a raw query works fine.  I always tried workarounds to make sure I could use the ORM, but I'll use raw SQL going forwards for complex queries.

Comment: This answer is now incorrect in that this can definitely be done in Django without resorting to raw SQL, at least when using Postgres. [See the answer below by @mrts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103275/14354604)

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the database backend you are using, which seems to be PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL can subtract dates directly, so the following will work:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class DaysInterval(Func):
    function = 'make_interval'
    template = '%(function)s(days:=%(expressions)s)'

qs = Assignment.objects.annotate(remaining_days=F('due_date') - Now())
qs.filter(remaining_days__lt=DaysInterval(F('extra_days')))
```

This results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT "assignments_assignment"."id", 
       "assignments_assignment"."extra_days", 
       "assignments_assignment"."due_date", 
       ("assignments_assignment"."due_date" - STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS "remaining_days" 
FROM   "assignments_assignment" 
WHERE  ("assignments_assignment"."due_date" - STATEMENT_TIMESTAMP())
        < (make_interval(DAYS:="assignments_assignment"."extra_days"))
```

For date difference calculations in other database backends see the [`Datediff`](https://github.com/michaeljtbrooks/mjtb-django-tools/blob/master/db_tools.py) function created by Michael Brooks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know , you can **not** pass an F() object as a **params** to another function since F() base class is a tree.Node type, A class for storing a tree graph which primarily used for filter constructs in the ORM.

see F() define at `django/db/models/expression.py` and Node at `django/utils/tree.py` (django 1.3.4)

```
class ExpressionNode(tree.Node):
    ...

class F(ExpressionNode):
    """
    An expression representing the value of the given field.
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(F, self).__init__(None, None, False)
        self.name = name

    def __deepcopy__(self, memodict):
        obj = super(F, self).__deepcopy__(memodict)
        obj.name = self.name
        return obj

    def prepare(self, evaluator, query, allow_joins):
        return evaluator.prepare_leaf(self, query, allow_joins)

    def evaluate(self, evaluator, qn, connection):
        return evaluator.evaluate_leaf(self, qn, connection)
```

you can do something like

```
Assignment.objects.filter(due_date__gt=F('due_date') - timedelta(days=1))
```

but not

```
Assignment.objects.filter(due_date__gt=cur_date - timedelta(days=F('extra_days')))
```

Correct me if i was wrong. Hope this little help.

Comment: Thanks.  But the last statement is what I functionally want to do.  The days have to come from the database.  I guess this is not possible in Django without resorting to raw SQL (which is a pretty simple query).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else looks for this, here's something that might be worth looking into.

I'm using Django 1.4 and am running into the exact same issue as the OP. Seems that the issue is probably due to `timedelta` and `datetime` needing to evaluate before being sent to the database, but the `F` object is inherently only going to resolve in the database.

I noticed that in Django 1.8, a new [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField) was introduced that looks like it would directly work like python's timedelta . This should mean that instead of needing to take the timedelta of an F object look up on an IntegerField, one could theoretically use a DurationField and then the F object wouldn't need to be in a timedelta at all. Unfortunately, due to dependencies, I'm not currently able to upgrade my project to 1.8 and test this theory.

If anyone else encounters this problem and is able to test my suggestion, I'd love to know. If I resolve my dependencies and can upgrade to 1.8, then I'll be sure to post back with my results.

Comment: Django 1.8 introduced [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/), and this may be what I'm looking for.  I wanted to try it out once I got the chance.

Comment: This is the best solution I found! My code looks like this: `.annotate(date_end=ExpressionWrapper(F('date_start') + Sum('days'), output_field=DateField()))`. I had to use `ExpressionWrapper` to provide the `output_field` parameter, otherwise Django complained about mixed types in the operation (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions)). Obviously, `days` is my model's `DurationField`.

Comment: @Filly I'm glad to hear the DurationField does work for this scenario. Thanks for posting!