# Dynamic range filter based on field in Django

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

I'm relatively new to Django and not familiar yet with Django Querysets. 
I want to filter a queryset by a datetime range based on a field.
In MySQL I would do

```
WHERE (start_time < NOW() - INTERVAL duration MINUTE)
```

Here start_time is a datetime and duration is an int for duration in minutes.

How would I do this in Django in a portable way? I know I could always use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra), but I would prefer it to work both in MySQL and Sqlite3. It seems that these database managers doesn't share any datetime functions.

Comment: This is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555247/django-time-difference-with-f-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'F' expressions in Queries to reference fields of the model within filter expressions (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)

This means that within the filter, it's possible to say 'where `time_a` is before `time_b`' for any particular row with:

```
filter(time_a__lt=F('time_b')
```

However, the problem arises because, as per [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555247/django-time-difference-with-f-object), `timedelta` won't accept the dynamic `F()` expression... and so it looks like custom SQL is required. However, you can test that automatically in Django on both sqlite and mysql to assert that it works on both.

Meanwhile, a particularly dirty solution which avoids custom SQL is to convert the `start_time` into Unix time which makes the maths easy.

```
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils.timezone import now


class Journey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    start_time = models.IntegerField()
    duration_minutes = models.IntegerField()


def current_journeys():
    unow = timegm(now().utctimetuple())
    q = Journey.objects.filter(start_time__gt=unow-60*F('duration_minutes'))
    return q.all()
```

Comment: Just tested this using `django.test.TestCase` and it works with both sqlite3 and mysql engines.

Comment: In my case though, it is not a fixed range. It depends on the duration field which varies for each row in the database. That's why I explicitly state the start_time and duration types.

Comment: I probably have to solve my problem in a way that avoids the issue altogether, but it would be nice to know if this is possible.

Comment: Seems to me that if you have `start_time` and `duration` on each row you could easily calculate an `end_time` and store that in the model - then you've got a very easy field to filter on that will be compatible across different engines. It wasn't clear to me that `duration` was from within each instance, rather than externally provided.

Comment: @Sten-Åke I've understood your question better now, linked to a related one and also updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Yes, I did add end_time and then used a normal range query in the end. And thanks to pointing me to F() expressions, I was not aware of them.

Comment: Your solution looks good at a glance. I probably accept your answer after i get some free time to test it.