# What is the replacement for DateModifierNode in new versions of Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I want to do a query based on two fields of a model, a date, offset by an int, used as a timedelta

```
model.objects.filter(last_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=F('interval')))
```

is a no-go, as a F() expression cannot be passed into a timedelta

A little digging, and I discovered `DateModifierNode` - though it seems it was removed in this commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/cbb5cdd155668ba771cad6b975676d3b20fed37b (from this now-outdated SO question [Django: Using F arguments in datetime.timedelta inside a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133829/django-using-f-arguments-in-datetime-timedelta-inside-a-query/24135138?s=1|0.2211#24135138))

the commit mentions:

> The .dates() queries were implemented by using custom Query, QuerySet,
>   and Compiler classes. Instead implement them by using expressions and
>   database converters APIs.

which sounds sensible, and like there should still be a quick easy way - but I've been fruitlessly looking for how to do that for a little too long - anyone know the answer?

Comment: You don't have to change model structure and add manually. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42390145/4070498).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.10 there's simpler method to do it but you need to change the model a little: use a DurationField. My model is as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    timeout = models.DurationField(default=86400 * 7)  # default: week
    last = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the query to find objects where `last` was before `now` minus `timeout` is:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(last__lt=datetime.datetime.now()-F('timeout'))
```

Comment: Not tested this - but assuming you have ;) looks like a much nicer solution! Will upgrade django soon

Answer (score 5):

Ah, answer from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F

Ticket.objects.annotate(
    expires=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('active_at') + F('duration'), output_field=DateTimeField()))
```

which should make my original query look like

```
model.objects.annotate(new_date=ExpressionWrapper(F('last_date') + F('interval'), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(new_date__gte=datetime.now())
```

Comment: seriously possible for `F('last_date') + F('interval')` and output is datetimefield? and it increased in days same as `timedelta(days=interval)`?

Comment: Subtracting a number from a date does not work for me as it is not recognized as a subtraction for the days. I'm using mysql.