# Django ORM: Filter on timedelta

Tags: python, django, filter, orm

I've got a field 'frequency' and i'd like use it in my filter.

My model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   frequency = models.IntegerField(default='60')
   last_checked = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'd like get my data some like it, but instead of '10' minutes I can put there 'frequency' field.

```
Foo.objects.filter(last_checked__lt=timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=10))
```

How can i do this? Or maybe I shoud go other way? Thanks for helpful tips.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297988/1637351 See other comment for better suggestion.

Comment: Actually this one is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145600/1637351 It would use `DurationField`