# How to perform an F() query with datetime field?

Tags: python, django

I want to do a query based on two fields of a model, a date, offset by an int, used as a timedelta

```
model.objects.filter(last_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=F('interval')))
```

My model goes this way:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    last_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    interval = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am using **Django 2.0** and **db.sqlite3**

I found some sources [What is the replacement for DateModifierNode in new versions of Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703016/what-is-the-replacement-for-datemodifiernode-in-new-versions-of-django) and [Making queries using F() and timedelta at django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158859/making-queries-using-f-and-timedelta-at-django?noredirect=1&lq=1) but they were not helpful.

some suggested to use duration field, but I want the interval to be entered in days desperately, whenever I use duration field , the admin needs to enter that in [days hh:mm:ss]  in admin forms.

And some gave a method

```
model.objects.filter(last_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)*F('interval'))
```

which isn't working in db.sqlite3 and returning errors.

Please suggest me some solution,like admin using duration field and entering only days or some solution with integer field of days.

Comment: What type is `interval`? Please post the relevant parts of your model.

Comment: it's integer type

Comment: @SiddanathamSaikalyan Maybe it would be best to use a `DurationField` for the `interval` and then register a custom [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) for the admin view, which allows entering just the number of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the situation this way:

```
class Line(models.Model):
  last_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  interval1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  interval2 = models.DurationField(default=0)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.interval2 = timedelta(days=self.interval1)
    super(Line, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I used two fields, and while saving I converted interval1(integer field) to interval2(DurationField) and excluded interval2 in the forms, then Filter can be applied easily.

```
  model.objects.filter(last_date__gte=datetime.now()- F('interval2'))
```